# Grouping records in one single row

Tags: database

I got this table having 3 rows for same ID

```
ID     City     State     Country
1      NULL      AZ         NULL
1      Phoenix   NULL       NULL
1      NULL      NULL       USA
```

Need to get the single row output

```
ID     City     State     Country
1      Phoenix   AZ        USA
```

Thanks,
P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your sample, you could do this (it will retrieve the non null values).

Now, this works with your sample (only 1 non NULL value by column).

```
select id, Max(City), Max(State), Max(Country)
From mytable
GROUP BY Id
```

see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/976a3/1)